# Contrained optimization [Maxima] R

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to solve the following a constrained maximization problem.

The example here is simply me trying to recreate a simple example.

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Obs=c(1,2,3,4,5)
Var1=c(11,15,16,19,20)
Var2=c(1.5,22,0.9,1.7,.1)
Var3=c(2.6,2.5,3.5,3.6,2.1)
Value_One = c(10,12.5,8.4,7.5,2.6)
Cost = c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.6,1.7)
Value_overall = c(10,21,31,4,29)
df=data.frame(Obs,Var1,Var2,Var3,Value_One,Cost,Value_overall)
var_sel=c('Var1','Var2')
coeff_sel=c(2.5,4.5)
gamma=.7
```

I have to run a constrained optimization problem an example of which is as follows (Note the exact values, does not matter. Please feel free to change them as you please):

```
Value_func = function(x){
  Value_var=x$Cost

  # - since the contrained optimum function is for minima.

  -((x$Value_overall+gamma*(x$Value_null-
  (as.matrix(x[var_sel])%*%(as.matrix(coeff_sel)))))-2*x[Cost])

}

#Please feel free to change the values below. 
#I just want to know where I am going wrong. The exact values do not matter here.

for (i2 in 1:nrow(df)){
  x=df[i2,]
  zzz=constrOptim(-1.2, Value_func, NULL,ui=1,ci=-1.3)

}
```

What I want to do is to run the above for each row of the dataframe. When I run the above example, I get the following error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Called from: f(theta, ...)
```

I tried to look for a solution and this is what I got but it does not seem to be applicable in my case ([R $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in constraOptim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276457/r-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors-in-constraoptim)).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but for the ```constrOptim```, you still need to pass x to the function. Additionally, I got errors on ```x[Cost]``` in your function. It seems like it should be ```Value_var```. FWIW, my error is ```Error in f(theta, ...) : unused argument (theta)```. My gut is saying that you need to explicitly decide which variable in ```df``` is going to be optimized. Right now, it's an entire data.frame.

Comment: Ok. That gives me something to work with. That was very helpful actually. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes a result without error. Changes to your code include:

1. Added `Value_null` to the data.frame
2. Changed the function argument to `costs` and modify the function after the matrix stuff.
3. Saved the results to `zzz` as a list instead of static.

If you design this as a matrix in the first place, you could utilize apply.

```
df <- data.frame(Obs=c(1,2,3,4,5)
                 ,Var1=c(11,15,16,19,20)
                 ,Var2=c(1.5,22,0.9,1.7,.1)
                 ,Var3=c(2.6,2.5,3.5,3.6,2.1)
                 ,Value_One = c(10,12.5,8.4,7.5,2.6)
                 ,Cost = c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.6,1.7)
                 ,Value_overall = c(10,21,31,4,29)
                 #added to match
                 ,Value_null = 5
)

var_sel=c('Var1','Var2')
coeff_sel=c(2.5,4.5)
gamma=.7

Value_func = function(costs){
  # - since the contrained optimum function is for minima.
  -((x$Value_overall+gamma*(x$Value_null-
                              (as.matrix(x[var_sel])%*%(as.matrix(coeff_sel)))))-2*costs)
}

for (i2 in 1:nrow(df)){
  x=df[i2,]
  zzz[[i2]]=constrOptim(1, Value_func, NULL,ui=1,ci=-1.3, x$Cost)
}
```

Or the `apply` approach. I don't like that I'm assigning `x <<- z` but it gives results.

```
Value_func = function(costs){
  # - since the contrained optimum function is for minima.
  -((x['Value_overall']+gamma*(x['Value_null']-
                              (x[var_sel]%*%(coeff_sel))))-2*costs)  
}

apply(df, 1, function(z) {
  x<<- z
  constrOptim(1, Value_func, NULL, ui = 1, ci = -1.3, z['Cost'])
}
)
```